# Foreign Key In Php to get data from another table

Tags: php

```
function show_username($connect)
 {
$output = '';  
  $query = "SELECT * from users";  
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
$output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>'; 
{  

  }  
  return $output;
}
function show_offer($connect) 
{  
  $output = '';  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM add_offer ORDER BY id DESC";  
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
  {
$output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-6">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel-body">';

   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$row["part_no"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["make"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["date_code"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["qty"].'</div>';  
   $output .= '<br>';  
       $output .= '<div style="float:left;font-size:9px;">'.$row["time"].'</div>';
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
  }  
  echo $output;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 1px solid #66512c;">
                                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #66512c;color: white;">
                                    Market Offers
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px;padding-left: 5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #66512c;">
                                <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <select name="category" id="user" class="form-control">  
                                    <option selected="" value="" class="form-control">All User Offers</option>  
                                     <?php echo show_username($connect); ?>  
                                </select>
                                    <div class="panel panel-body" id="show_offer">  
                                <?php echo show_offer($connect);?>  
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>

</div>
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#user').change(function(){  
var user_id = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{user_id:user_id},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_offer').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  

});</script> 
 <?php  
//load_data.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customer");
$output = ''; 
if(isset($_POST["user_id"])) 
{  
  if($_POST["user_id"] != '')  
  {  
       $query = "SELECT * FROM add_offer  WHERE user_id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' ORDER BY id DESC";  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $query = "SELECT * FROM add_offer ORDER BY id DESC";  
  }  
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
  {  
       $output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-6">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel-body">'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$row["part_no"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["make"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["date_code"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["qty"].'</div>';  
   $output .= '<br>';  
       $output .= '<div style="float:left;font-size:9px;">'.$row["time"].'</div>';
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
  }  
  echo $output;
}?>
```

In this above code I have used functions to take data from 2 seperate table and I want to display the table in the following format as 
name from users table
part_no,make,date_code,qty from add_offers table
the image shows my output [market_offers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9gJE.jpg)

I want the data not to be selected by dropdown but has to display whole data as first with name from users table and followed by users part_no from add_offers table.

Also the timestamp display as 2018-03-22 12.40.55 which i want as 22-03-2018 12.40.55

Comment: Where is your load_data.php code?

Comment: What is your actual question? You seem to list things you want but not what you need to know to get there.

Comment: What a terrible mess! You managed to mix PHP, HTML, SQL and JavaScript code in one script. My first advise is to separate all this into different isolated parts and only after that fix all the rest

Comment: Look what BBoM, separation of concerns, single responsibility, MVC and ORM mean. Fix all design issues and all other issues will vanish by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to change your code as bellow:

```
function show_username($connect)
 {
$output = '';  
  $query = "SELECT * from users order by id asc";  
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
$output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>'; 
{  

  }  
  return $output;
}

function show_offer($connect) 
{  
  $output = '';  
  $user_query = "SELECT * from users order by id asc";  
      $user_res = mysqli_query($connect, $user_query );  
      $user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_res);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM add_offer where user_id = ".$user_row['id']." ORDER BY id DESC";  
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
  {
$output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-6">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel-body">';

   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$row["part_no"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["make"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($row["date_code"])).'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["qty"].'</div>';  
   $output .= '<br>';  
       $output .= '<div style="float:left;font-size:9px;">'.$row["time"].'</div>';
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
  }  
  echo $output;
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 1px solid #66512c;">
                                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #66512c;color: white;">
                                    Market Offers
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px;padding-left: 5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #66512c;">
                                <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <select name="category" id="user" class="form-control">  
                                    <option selected="" value="" class="form-control">All User Offers</option>  
                                     <?php echo show_username($connect); ?>  
                                </select>
                                    <div class="panel panel-body" id="show_offer">  
                                <?php echo show_offer($connect);?>  
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>

</div>
```

Java Script Code:

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#user').change(function(){  
var user_id = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{user_id:user_id},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_offer').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  

});</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php  
//load_data.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "customer");
$output = ''; 
if(isset($_POST["user_id"])) 
{  
  if($_POST["user_id"] != '')  
  {  
       $query = "SELECT * FROM add_offer  WHERE user_id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' ORDER BY id DESC";  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $query = "SELECT * FROM add_offer ORDER BY id DESC";  
  }  
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))  
  {  
       $output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-6">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';  
       $output .= '<div class="panel-body">'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$row["part_no"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["make"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["date_code"].'</div>'; 
   $output .= '<div style="padding:1px;float:left;">'.$row["qty"].'</div>';  
   $output .= '<br>';  
       $output .= '<div style="float:left;font-size:9px;">'.$row["time"].'</div>';
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
       $output .= '</div>';  
  }  
  echo $output;
}?>
```